# cloned file input submit file without file name in IE8 and with file name in FF

Tags: jquery, jsp, internet-explorer, firefox

Full description in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118784/struts-2-multiple-file-upload-with-just-one-file-input-in-ie-8-without-flash-s/32118785#32118785).

I am working on cloning file input fields to get multiple file uploading to work in IE 8. I am using these code:

```
function addField(){
        if ( $('form input:file').last().val() != ""  ){
        var lastfile = $('form input:file').last();
        var countfile = ($('form input:file').length)+1;
        var always = $('#filesUploadId');
        var cloned = always.clone();
        cloned.attr("name", "correoForm.filesUpload");
        cloned.attr("id", "file_"+countfile);
        cloned.insertAfter(lastfile);
}
```

But, it is working differently in IE 8 and FF, but I want them work in both.

If I have selected 1.txt, 2.jpg, 3.zip, in IE8 I have three files(actually four, but the last one has no file name, so it is ok), but in FF I have 4, which are 1, 2, 3 and 1.txt. 1.txt is repeated.

So:

- Why don't I get the file name in IE 8? Although it is working, I'd like to ask.
- Why can I have the file name in FF?
- How can I have a "Clear All" function, to remove all the other file input except first one? I'd like to preserve the first file input field, with its style and its event bundler, but remove its content. If copying a file input will cause files repeating in FF, copy the first file input will not remove its content.

I am making a Plank for this. Hope to get it working today.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it helps, but when i had a form like that, i used an array as a name of the file input... i'll explain myself in code:

```
cloned.attr("name", "correoForm.filesUpload[]");
```

i added the [] at the end of the name, so instead of 3 inputs with the same name, that could follow to be handled as only one input, it will be an array of that input.

and for removing the extra inputs something like this, ( i see that you're using jquery)

```
function removeExtraInputs() {
    $('input[type=file]').not(':first').remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am using struts 2 and it handles fields with same name alone. What is left is define an array in Action class with this name. So maybe it is not necessary in my case. And the removing part I will try.